# How to show jQuery is working/waiting/loading?

Tags: jquery, jquery-load, jquery-post

How do I show a loading picture and/or message to the user ?
If possible, would I like to know how to make it full screen with grey-dimmed background. Kinda like when viewing the large picture from some galleries (sorry, no example link).

Currently do I add a CSS class which has the image and other formating, but its not working for some reason.
Results from the search do get inserted into the div.

HTML

```
<div id="searchresults"></div>
```

CSS

```
div.loading {
  background-image: url('../img/loading.gif'); 
  background-position: center;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#searchform').submit(function(){
    $('#searchresults').addClass('loading');
    $.post('search.php', $('#'+this.id).serialize(),function(result){
      $('#searchresults').html(result);
    });
    $('#searchresults').removeClass('loading');
    return false;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are calling `removeClass('loading')` immediately after you issued ajax call, not after it is finished.

You could do `removeClass('loading')` in ajax callback. `$.post` allows to provide only `success` callback:

```
jQuery.post( url, [ data ], [ success(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) ], [ dataType ] )
```

And loading picture should be removed in any case - succes or failure, so it is better to use `complete` callback of `$.ajax()`:

```
$('#searchform').submit(function(){
  $('#searchresults').addClass('loading');

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'search.php',
    data:  $('#'+this.id).serialize(),
    success: function(result){
      $('#searchresults').html(result);
    },
    complete: function() {
      $('#searchresults').removeClass('loading');
    }
  });
  return false;
});
```

See more about callbacks in "Callback Functions" section in [$.ajax() docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    $("#contentLoading").ajaxSend(function(r, s) {
        $(this).show();
        $("#ready").hide();
    });

    $("#contentLoading").ajaxStop(function(r, s) {
        $(this).hide();
        $("#ready").show();
    });
```

This will display `#contentLoading` which is my progress `gif` when I start an ajax and hide it when ajax stops.